# How to make my node restart every X seconds

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, nodejs

I want to make my node command (node index.js for example) repeat every X hours. I want it to run the commandline `node .`, then after X hours to exit the process and node it again. Any ideas?

More info (AFTER EDIT):

Ubuntu Server 18.04

Comment: Done @K7AAY. Added extra info.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with cron job [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) or try a systemd timer service. The latter I've used several times. You'll need to create a service and a corresponding timer for it: [A timer Example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)
Your script is a service then. So you'd start it with [systemctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemctl.1.html)

Comment: Oh are there any videos that can help me out through this? I'm pretty new to ubuntu-linux.